# How to enforce write lock on table row using JPA/Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, locking, isolation-level

Is there an easy way to enforce somewhat concatenation of Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ and write locking for select statements, so once i've read a row in the transaction T1, all other transactions attempting to read that same row will hang untill T1 is commited/rolledback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on your service method or wherever you want this annotation to open a transaction with the isolation level of Repeatable_Read that you want

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
```

remember to import that annotation from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation;`

and not from `javax.*`

If you want to also lock concurent reads go to your JPA method that brings the entities to you, if you use one of the defaults, then define it again in your repo, and use the following annotation

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
List<MyEntity> findByName(String name);
```

`@Lock` must be called inside a transaction otherwise it throws an exception. So the @Transactional before is mandatory

Check here for more information  [Lock Modes in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking#2-pessimisticwrite)

Comment: @user1079475 check updated answer for locking also reads

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need [pessimistic lockin](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#Pessimistic_Locking)g using PESIMISTIC_WRITE strategy